# reclaim rangeslider space and make it wider

Tags: jquery, mobile, rangeslider

I am trying to get rid of the spaces that are above the rangeslider. I thought hiding the labels was what I needed to do but that only made the space blank. How can I get rid of this space?

I saw "margin:0" in another post and tried that but it didn't work.

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="range-1a" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="-10" max="50" value="-10" step="10">
    <label for="range-1b" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="-10" max="50" value="50" step="10">
</div>
```

Comment: I found a way to get rid of the margin. setting margin:0 in my own css as an important override didn't work so I found it in the original css file and commented it out. That seems to work for me.      .ui-rangeslider .ui-rangeslider-sliders {
 position: relative;
 overflow: visible;
 height: 30px;
 /* margin: .5em 68px;*/
    } Now all I have to figure out is how to suppress the size of the input boxes that are associated with the slider so they don't take up space.

Comment: I fixed the rest with some javascript:     $(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({
      position: 'relative',
      display: 'inline-block',
      height: '0px',
      width: '0px',
      margin: '0px',
      overflow: 'hidden'
    }));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collapsed the inputs with this.

```
$(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({
  position: 'relative',
  display: 'inline-block',
  height: '0px',
  width: '0px',
  margin: '0px',
  overflow: 'hidden'
}));
```